# Setting focus on LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, setfocus

I am trying to set focus on a LinearLayout view when returning to an activity from another activity. The scenario:

I have one activity with a bunch of LinearLayout items (with stuff in them), some of which are text, others photos. Let's say the top most of 20 is a TextView and the rest are photos. When I leave this activity (to take a picture), activity goes to the top of the list where the TextView is - no matter what I do.

How do I force the focus back on the item that I was on before the new activity was triggered?

I have already tried this with no success:

[[How Linear Layout get Focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480360/how-linear-layout-get-focus][1])

I am currently trying to force the focus by remembering the previous view without success (though I can see the code being executed). The in my main activity:

```html
 @Override
 public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();

     // See if we had a field with focus previously...
     if (mPreviousView != null) {
      if (mPreviousView.isFocusable()) {
       mPreviousView.requestFocus();
      }
      
     }

 }
...

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

  mPreviousView = this.getCurrentFocus();
 
 }
```

I am dynamically setting the focus in the LinearLayout:

```html
 private void initialize() {
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  inflater.inflate(R.layout.field_photo_picker, this);
  
  // To allow focus to be returned to control after taking photo
  this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
  this.setFocusable(true);
  this.setClickable(true);
```

And finally the XML for the LinearLayout:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:text="" />
    
    <LinearLayout 
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     
            <TextView
          android:id="@+id/photoValue"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:textSize="17sp"
          android:textStyle="normal"
          android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
          android:text="" />
    
        <ImageButton 
          android:id="@+id/photoPicker"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/form_photo"
    android:padding ="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_weight="0"
      />
     
     </LinearLayout>
    
    <View
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/grey" />
    
</LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

Comment: try to store your `mPreviousView` as static in somewhere else, so it doesn't get lost when activity is destroyed

Comment: It isn't getting lost. I can step there and see it is happy. Just doesn't get focus.

Comment: does `mPreviousView.requestFocus();` get called? check

Comment: also make your textview and other views focusable, you made `this.setFocusable(true);` which doesn't make sense

Comment: It does hit the code for requestFocus() and returns true, but I will try and make the rest of the contained views focusable too.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick - making the other elements in the LinearLayout focus-able. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your `textview` and other views `focusable`, you made `this.setFocusable(true);` which doesn't make sense

Comment: While this seems to have fixed it for most of the focus issues, I still have one where if the TextView has focus and I call another Activity, even when I force the focus to the field that activated the Activity, it still returns focus to the TextView that previously had focus. However if the TextView does not have focus, everything works fine.